# adding new rows in excel without breaking a vba macro that uses Range.Value

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've written a macro in VBA that simply fills in a given cell's value from another cell in that sheet. I do this for lots of cells in the sheet, and I'm doing it like so:

```
Range("B3").Value = Range("B200")
Range("B4").Value = Range("B201")
'etc.
```

Now, I am often adding values by inserting new rows, so I might insert a new row
between B200 and B201, which will break the macro because it doesn't autoupdate when 
I insert the new row.

How can I code the macro so it autoupdates the cell references when I insert new rows or columns?

Comment: If there are couple of cells then as Shiin suggested naming the range will help but if you have lot of cells (1-500) like you mentioned in the comments then this procedure of naming the cells will really get painful, I am afraid...

Comment: Yeah, there are LOTS of cells - so is there a better way??

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way. You have to individually name all 500 cells. There is one alternative though which is less painful and involves editing your code slightly. Would that help?

Comment: yes please, Siddharth - what is it??

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to make sure the ROW you want to retrieve values from has a unique value in it that you can .FIND anytime you want, then grab your values from column B of that found cell's row.  So right now you want to get a value in B200 and A200 always has the text in it: **"Final Total"** and that is unique.

```
Dim MyRNG As Range

Set MyRNG = Range("A:A").Find("Final Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Range("B3").Value = Range("B" & MyRNG.Row)
Range("B4").Value = Range("B" & MyRNG.Row + 1)
```

Comment: Would you please click the upvote arrow on this answer then to mark it as accepted?  Thanks.

Comment: it won't let me - something about not having enough reputation points

Answer (score 1):

Try giving a name to the range. If you refer to the range by name Excel searches for it and retrieves the rows that defines it. Range names update their definition when new rows are added.

Adding to the above, i think this tutorial illustrates my point:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p6.html this is how to define the name of the range.

This tutorial explains how to use it on macros and vba:
http://excel.tips.net/T003106_Using_Named_Ranges_in_a_Macro.html

I hope this helps :D

Comment: Hi Shiin, How exactly will this help?

Comment: Hi Shiin, How exactly doI do this?  Say I currently use rows 1-500 in the macro.  Do I give that entire range a name?  And if so - say I call it "Range1", how do I refer to the cells in a way that won't break when I insert a new row after, say, row 250?

Comment: Edited my post for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer but an alternative.**

Naming your range is the way to go as Shiin suggested but then if you have 500 cells then like I mentioned earlier, naming 500 cells and using them in your code can be very painful. The alternative is to use smart code. Let's take an example

Let's say you have a code like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Range("B3").Value = Range("B200")
    Range("B4").Value = Range("B201")
    Range("B5").Value = Range("B201")
    ' And
    ' So On
    ' till
    Range("B500").Value = Range("B697")
End Sub
```

The best way to write this code is like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 200 To 697
        Range("B" & i - 197).Value = Range("B" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

and say if you insert a line at say row 300 then simply break the above code in two parts

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 200 To 299
        Range("B" & i - 197).Value = Range("B" & i)
    Next i

    For i = 301 To 698
        Range("B" & i - 197).Value = Range("B" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

So every time you insert a row, simply break the for loop into an extra part. This looks tedious but is much better than naming 500 cells and using them in your code.

**If you are planning to use the macro only once (i.e for 1 time use) then read ahead**.

If you are worried that when the user inserts the row then the cells are not updated then you can instead of assigning a value, assign a formula.

For example

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=B200"
```

This will put a formula `=B200` in cell `B3`. So next time when you insert a row so that the 200th row moves it's position, you will notice that the formula automatically gets updated in cell `B3`

HTH